# Python script should send me mail when there is any exception

Tags: python, smtp

I want my Python script to send me mail me when there is any exception. I have tried some code related to SMTP that I found, but unfortunately it's not executing and showing an error.  Please help me to find out the main problem.

The SMTP code:

```
import smtplib
import string

SERVER = 'localhost'
SUBJECT = "Test email from Python"
TO = "abc.def@defghij.com"
FROM = "python@mydomain.com"
text = "Sample of mail"
BODY = string.join(("From: %s" % FROM,"To: %s" % TO,"Subject: %s" %SUBJECT ,"",text), "\r\n")

server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER) #Here in this line it showing error 

server.sendmail(FROM,TO,BODY)

server.quit()
```

> ** error message *** server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
>
> socket.error: (10047, 'Address family not supported by protocol family: See http://wiki.python.org/jython/NewSocketModule#IPV6addresssupport')

Comment: did you try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`?

Comment: have you tried to leave the argument as blank `server = smtplib.SMTP()`

Comment: ya I tried as
        SERVER = '127.0.0.1'
and same problem as posted one.

widout single qotation its showing error
        SERVER=127.0.0.1 #ERROR

Comment: When I am trying `server = smtplib.SMTP()` , its showing error in `server.sendmail(FROM,TO,BODY)`

Comment: do you have a smtp server running at your localhost ?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code with Jython 2.5.3 and Python 2.7 and it works if I change `SERVER` from `localhost` to real SMTP server. I took SMTP server address from my email client configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with yagmail, it will make it all much more convenient:

```
from yagmail import SMTP
SMTP(FROM).send(TO, SUBJECT, text)
```

It really requires only that much, and if you do some setup you're registered and safe (no need to write your username and password in script).

Read more about it at [github](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).